# Getting Exception in Summing the values of a column of a table in SQL using ASP.Net

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to add the values of a column of a table. My table looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlPZx.png)

I want to add the values  of months column for a specific id. My code looks like this:

```
  public int MonthSum(int id)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            string query = "select sum(months) from PayTable where ID=@ID group by ID";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,connection);

            command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.Parameters.Add("ID", SqlDbType.Int);

            command.Parameters["ID"].Value = id;
            connection.Open();

            int total = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
            connection.Close();
            return total;
        }
```

Why I am getting exception here??

Comment: On which line are you getting the exception. Please provide the full exception.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: invalid object name 'PayTable' .. This is the exception

Comment: And do you have a PayTable table in the database you are connecting to? Is it placed in the dbo schema?

Comment: Check your connection string and verify you are connecting to the proper database and that the table "PayTable" EXISTS in the database you are trying to connect to.

Comment: Make sure you run the Update to commit the changes. Then I would recommend going into SSMS and verifying the table was created in the DB with the name you are expecting under the dbo schema.

Comment: The exception that you are getting is saying that your DB schema does not contain the table "PayTable" . Your image shows that you have the design for this Table. I can only surmise that it (the Table) is has not been created successfully in the DB schema that you are connecting to with your code. Check your DB connection and the actual tables in the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't provide more information about the exception, it's only guessing, but you may have a problem adding the parameter as "ID" instead of "@ID". I think that SqlCommand expects the name with the @.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) some Microsoft documentation with an example very similar to what you are doing.